# Recompile only changed files in Go when using C++ lib

Tags: c++, go, go-build

I am new to go. I use [go-tdlib](https://github.com/zelenin/go-tdlib) which in turn uses [tdlib](https://github.com/tdlib/td) written in C++. First time the compilation took about 15-20 minutes, then I literally added one commented line to my Go main func (I just copypasted the example from [go-tdlib](https://github.com/zelenin/go-tdlib), so it is just one small main func) and when I want to run the program it again takes 15-20 minutes to compile it. Is there any way to recompile only changed file? I tried `go build` and `go install` and I did not find yet any helpful solutions to this.

As I understand, Go compiles everything to one executable, and any change to one file triggers recompilation of everything. Is this correct? Is there any way to stop this? It is really annoying to wait 15-20 minutes when you added only one line to your main func.

Btw, I think it's due to the C++ lib, because if I remove all usages of the lib from the code, then it compiles as fast as expected.